# Get table id on click of button

Tags: jquery, html

Consider the following mark-up:

```
<div class="attachments">
<div class="form-group first-item">
  <label class="control-label col-md-4">Some Label</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <input type="file" multiple id="first-item-input" class="inputfile" />
           <label for="first-item-input">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17">
                 <path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z" />
              </svg>
              <span>Choose a file&hellip;</span>
              <input type="hidden" value="Some Hidden Value" id="first-input-hidden-value" />
           </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <button type="submit" id="first-item-btn" class="btn btn-default attachment-upload">Upload</button>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
     <div class="box">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table class="table table-bordered attachment-table" id="first-item-table">
                    <thead>
                       <tr>
                          <th>...</th>
                          <th>...</th>
                          <th>...</th>
                          <th>...</th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                 </table>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

The above mark-up is used numerous times with id's being changed accordingly e.g. `second-item-input, second-item-btn, second-item-table` and so on **(upto 10 but not limited)**. I am trying to get the table id of each time a user clicks the appropriate `button` e.g. if the user clicks button with id `first-item-btn` then the table id which should be return to me is `first-item-table` and so on for each button click.

So far this is what I have:

```
$('.attachment-upload').click(function () {
    var buttonId = this.id,
        tableId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('table').attr('id');
    console.log(tableId);
});
```

The above works but it seems to be chained a lot so I was wondering is there a another way or is this the only way I can go about it.

Comment: Try jquery `.closest()` https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: can you change the markup at all to add a data-attribute? e.g. add `data-id="1"` on the button, and the table to have id "item-table-1" instead, then you can just do `tableId = "item-table-" + $(this).data("id");` assuming the naming pattern always stays the same. Then this functionality is de-coupled from the hierarchy of the HTML, which might conceivably change if a new layout is introduced, or something.

Comment: @ADyson yes I can change the markup and add data-attribute, seems like a good way to go about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.closest('.attachments').find('table')`

```
$('.attachment-upload').click(function() {
  var buttonId = this.id,
    tableId = $(this).closest('.attachments').find('table').attr('id');
  console.log(tableId);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.attachment-upload').click(function() {
  var buttonId = this.id,
    tableId = $(this).closest('.attachments').find('table').attr('id');
  console.log(tableId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="attachments">
  <div class="form-group first-item">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4">Some Label</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="file" multiple id="first-item-input" class="inputfile" />
          <label for="first-item-input">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17">
                 <path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z" />
              </svg>
              <span>Choose a file&hellip;</span>
              <input type="hidden" value="Some Hidden Value" id="first-input-hidden-value" />
           </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button type="submit" id="first-item-btn" class="btn btn-default attachment-upload">Upload</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered attachment-table" id="first-item-table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>...</th>
                    <th>...</th>
                    <th>...</th>
                    <th>...</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @Code No problem. Happy to help

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Jquery Closest Function](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.attachment-upload').click(function () {
   var buttonId = this.id,
   tableId =$(this).closest(".attachments").find('table').attr('id');
   console.log(tableId);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help